# Django - Non-class-based views authorization

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, authorization

I follow this tutorial http://www.effectivedjango.com/tutorial/authzn.html. There we create class, which we should extend with class-based view. So what if I have method-defined view? What should I do?

```
def some_private_view(request):
    ...

class LoggedInMixin(object):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(LoggedInMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `login_required` decorator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator.

You can't decorate a class, because a decorator is a function that takes a function `x` as an argument, does something with this function `x` and returns it afterwards. This is why you need the rather "useless" `dispatch` method here, that just calls it's parent without doing anything, because a class is not a function.

---

Edit: A note for later - If you'd like to skip the "useless" `dispatch` method you could write a Mixin (a small little class that just overrides a particular function) that just adds `@method_decorator(login_required)to`dispatch`and use it with all`View`s.

You actually don't need to do that really. There's [django braces](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces) out there that does this for you. Then you can just do:

```
class AdminView(braces.views.LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  # Do some logged-in user stuff here
```

Comment: login_required work perfect, thank you. But I didn't understand your second subparagraph. Could you be more precisely, please (my English is not good)? For what purposes we create LoggedInMixin class?

Comment: I just had a closer look at your tutorial link - it's doing exactly what I was proposing. Just continue the tutorial :)  It saves you typing the dispatch method every time you want a view that requires login. This would have been about 500 lines just dispatch for my medium sized project now